# Twilio SMS - status callback response has no MessageSid and MessageStatus

Tags: java, kotlin, twilio, sms

We are using Twilio Programmable Messaging for sending SMS, in our Kotlin backend service with Twilio SDK.

*Gradle dependency*

```
implementation("com.twilio.sdk:twilio:7.51.0")
```

Also, we are tracking the delivery status of the sent SMS messages. For that, we need to set a status callback before sending an SMS.

```
val creator = Message.creator(to, from, textMessage)
        .setStatusCallback(webhook.smsStatus)
```

#### Receiving message status

Our other service is set up for receiving a status callback.

```
@PostMapping(path = ["events"], consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE])
@ResponseStatus(NO_CONTENT)
fun receiveSmsStatus(status: SmsStatus) {
    communicationsService.processSmsStatus(status.MessageSid, status.MessageStatus)
}
```

Everything is working fine and we successfully receive and process SMS delivery statuses.
But every 100th status callback contains payload with **nullable** `MessageSid` and `MessageStatus`. At the same time, it contains payload **with** `From` and `To` phone numbers.

Why might this happen? And is it okay for MessageSid and MessageStatus to be NULL? I thought these fields are required.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest opening a ticket with Twilio support via the Twilio Console (upper right corner under ? - Submit a ticket). If you can associate the outbound SMS SID returned when calling the /Messages resource with the associated statusCallback (say by matching the number the SMS was sent to since the MessageSID is null), that may help Twilio support identify the issue.

Screenshots in the ticket will also be useful for them.